# Win10 touch keyboard on login screen

Tags: windows-10, tablet, touch-typing

Until recently the touch keyboard on my Toshiba encore showed up when I touched the pin entry field, now it doesn't. Windows 10 runs in tablet mode and once logged in the keyboard works as expected, i.e. touch an input field and the keyboard comes up. And it's reproducible: login screen, no keyboard. Logged in, keyboard works flawless.
What extra (-hidden) settings are there for the logon session?

Comment: probably broken as of the November update?

Comment: Check whether the service "Touch keyboard and handwriting panel service" startup type is set to Automatic and is running

Comment: The TabletInputService is on automatic and running.